# why can't i pickle a nested dict or list inside a class in pPython?

Tags: python

I'm currently making a text-based game, but when I try to pickle my player Class it saves everything except the dictionaries and the lists. Here is my code for saving the game:

```
# Saving
def save():
    os.system('cls')
    print("As", player.Name, "opens the book, series of names and stats are written throughout the pages...")

    ask = input("Write your name and stats in the book?\n[" + Fore.GREEN + "Y" + Fore.RESET + "]Yes "
                                                                                              "\n[" + Fore.GREEN + "N" + Fore.RESET + "]No\n> ").upper()
    if ask == "Y" or ask == "YES":
        print("(Which Save File will you save into?)")
        print("[" + Fore.GREEN + "1" + Fore.RESET + "]Save_File1")
        print("[" + Fore.GREEN + "2" + Fore.RESET + "]Save_File2")
        print("[" + Fore.GREEN + "3" + Fore.RESET + "]Save_File3")
        print("[" + Fore.GREEN + "4" + Fore.RESET + "]Save_File4")
        save_choice = input('> ')
        print()
        if save_choice == '1':
            with open("Save_File1.pkl", "wb") as save_file:
                pickle.dump(player, save_file)  # Creates the file and puts the data into the file
        elif save_choice == '2':
            pickle.dump(player, open('Save_File2.pkl', 'wb'))  # Creates the file and puts the data into the file
        elif save_choice == '3':
            pickle.dump(player, open('Save_File3.pkl', 'wb'))  # Creates the file and puts the data into the file
        elif save_choice == '4':
            pickle.dump(player, open('Save_File4.pkl', 'wb'))
        else:
            print('Invalid Command')
            input('> ')
            save()
        print("Your progress has been saved!")
        input("> ")
```

and here is my code for loading the game:

```
# Loading
def load():
    while True:
     os.system('cls')
     print("( Load a save file )")
     print("[" + Fore.GREEN + "1" + Fore.RESET + "]Save_File1")
     print("[" + Fore.GREEN + "2" + Fore.RESET + "]Save_File2")
     print("[" + Fore.GREEN + "3" + Fore.RESET + "]Save_File3")
     print("[" + Fore.GREEN + "4" + Fore.RESET + "]Save_File4")
     load_choice = input('> ')
     global player
     if load_choice == '1':

         with open("Save_File1.pkl", "rb") as save_file:
            player = pickle.load(save_file)


     elif load_choice == '2':

         player = pickle.load(open('Save_File2.pkl', 'rb'))  # Loads the file


     elif load_choice == '3':

         player = pickle.load(open('Save_File3.pkl', 'rb'))  # Loads the file

     elif load_choice == '4':

         player = pickle.load(open('Save_File4.pkl', 'rb'))  # Loads the File
```

Here is the player stats:

```
# Player Stats
class Player(object):
    Name = ""
    Class = ""
    Race = ""
    HP = 0
    MaxHP = 0
    SP = 0
    MaxSP = 0
    BP = 0
    MaxBP = 100
    Power = 0
    Vitality = 0
    Dexterity = 0
    Intelligence = 0
    Perception = 0
    Persona = 0
    XP = 0
    MXP = 50
    Gold = 50
    Lv = 1
    Offence = 0
    Defence = 0
    Base_Offence = 0
    Base_Defence = 0
    Offence_Mod = 0
    Defence_Mod = 0
    Bounty = 0
    Reputation = {"Commoner": 0, "Noble": 0, "Peasant": 0, "Adventurer": 0}
    events = []
    Lang = ["Common"] # This one doesn't Save
    Skills = {}  # This one doesn't Save
    Status_Effects = []
    Key_Items = []
    Health_Potion = 0
    MaxHealth_Potion = 5
    Ether_Potion = 0
    MaxEther_Potion = 5
    Antidote_Potion = 0
    MaxAntidote_Potion = 5
    location = ""
    weapon = ""
    armr = ""

player = Player()
```

Nothing I google helps so I hope i could get help here.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Figured it out! I was using class variables instead of Instance variables!
I switched the Player Class to this:

```
# Player Stats
class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Name = ""
        self.Class = ""
        self.Race = ""
        self.HP = 0
        self.MaxHP = 0
        self.SP = 0
        self.MaxSP = 0
        self.BP = 0
        self.MaxBP = 100
        self.Power = 0
        self.Vitality = 0
        self.Dexterity = 0
        self.Intelligence = 0
        self.Perception = 0
        self.Persona = 0
        self.XP = 0
        self.MXP = 50
        self.Gold = 50
        self.Lv = 1
        self.Offence = 0
        self.Defence = 0
        self.Base_Offence = 0
        self.Base_Defence = 0
        self.Offence_Mod = 0
        self.Defence_Mod = 0
        self.Bounty = 0
        self.Reputation = {"Commoner": 0, "Noble": 0, "Peasant": 0, "Adventurer": 0}
        self.events = []
        self.Lang = ["Common"]
        self.Skills = {}
        self.Status_Effects = []
        self.Key_Items = []
        self.Health_Potion = 0
        self.MaxHealth_Potion = 5
        self.Ether_Potion = 0
        self.MaxEther_Potion = 5
        self.Antidote_Potion = 0
        self.MaxAntidote_Potion = 5
        self.location = ""
        self.weapon = ""
        self.armr = ""

player = Player()
```

I'm sort of new to programming so this helped a lot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made class variables, not instance variables. None of the data you want to save is part of the instance, so it doesn't get saved. (The parts that *did* get saved wouldn't have been saved either, except that you inadvertently shadowed the class variables with new instance variables later without realizing it, in code you didn't post.)

Use instance variables.